# Heroku S3 Env variables

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, amazon-s3, carrierwave

I'm trying to use carrierwave to upload images to S3. It works locally but when I go to deploy to heroku I get the following error:

```
   ArgumentError: Missing required arguments: aws_access_key_id, aws_secret_
     access_key
```

The keys are definitely set because I can see them when I run heroku:config

I've searched every answer I could find on stack and I searched through every answer on the first 3 pages of Google. None of them have worked.

I know the uploading works so it's not the code that's a problem. What settings or variables do I have to set to make this work?

Please help, I can't move forward with my app until this is done (so I can deploy to heroku again without it being stopped because of this error.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some info:

---

**Environment Variables**

> You've got a problem with the calling of your environment variables in
>   Heroku. [ENV vars](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Environment_variable) are basically variables stored in the OS /
>   environment, which means you've got to set them for each environment
>   you attempt to your deploy application

`heroku config` should should the ENV vars you've set. If you don't see `ENV['AWS_ACCESS_KEY']` etc, it means you've not set them correctly, which as explained is as simple as calling the command `heroku config:add YOUR_ENV_VAR=VAR`

---

**Figaro**

I wanted to recommend using [Figaro](https://github.com/laserlemon/figaro) for this

This is a gem which basically stores local ENV vars in `config/application.yml`. This allows you to store ENV variables locally; but more importantly, [allows you to sync them with Heroku](https://github.com/laserlemon/figaro#how-does-it-work-with-heroku) using this command:

```
rake figaro:heroku
```

This will set your `env` vars on Heroku, allowing you to use them with Carrierwave as recommended in the other answers

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you have set the ENV variables on Heroku, but you need to hook those up to CarrierWave.

In `config/initializers/fog.rb`

```
CarrierWave.configure do |config|
  config.fog_credentials = {
    :provider               => 'AWS',
    :aws_access_key_id      => Rails.configuration.s3_access_key_id,
    :aws_secret_access_key  => Rails.configuration.s3_secret_access_key,
  }
end
```

In your `environments/<environment>.rb` file

```
Rails.application.configure do
  config.s3_access_key_id     = ENV['S3_ACCESS_KEY_ID']
  config.s3_secret_access_key = ENV['S3_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY']
end
```

This sets your Rails config to the ENV variables on Heroku which makes them available as `Rails.configuration.<key>`